# How to add a value at some list[x][y] in C++?

Tags: c++, list, c++11, iterator

I am trying to add some value at cost[x][y] and the list must be a pointer type.
I declared the list like this:

```
list<int>* cost = new list<int>[V]; // V being user input
```

And here I'm trying to add the value "c" at the place of cost[x][y]. How am I supposed to add that .When I try to use iterator as below it says

1. "Debug Assertion Failed"
2. "Unable to increment end point iterator"

The Code:

```
    void addCost(int x, int y, int c) // adds cost in cost[x][y] and cost[y][x] indicies
    {
        auto it = cost[x].begin();
        advance(it, y);
        *it = c;
    }
```

Comment: "_and the list must be a pointer type_": Very unlikely. `new` on a container type is seldom useful. It is not clear why you want an array of lists. Why not `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`, which should be the fist thing that comes to mind for a 2d grid? `std::list` doesn't have random access iterators. It cannot be used efficiently to access random positions.

Comment: You can also use `std::map` for a 2D list.

Comment: thanks both of you for the reply... Well I might switch to using vector, that would be easier I guess. @SolvedGames I will check it out thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the lists will be initially empty. So, having 0 elements.

So, you can write `cost[x]` and can get an iterator. That is OK. But, as said, the list is empty. So, if you try to advance the iterator, it will fail.

Because, `it` will be equal to `end()` in the beginning. And this cannot be advanced.

Else, it would work . . .

Some demo example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

constexpr size_t SIZE = 10;

int main() {
    size_t numberOfElementsX{ SIZE };
    size_t numberOfElementsY{ SIZE };
    
    std::list<int>* cost = new std::list<int>[numberOfElementsX];

    for (size_t i = 0; i < numberOfElementsX; ++i)
        cost[i].resize(numberOfElementsY);

    auto it = cost[3].begin();
    std::advance(it, 5);

    *it = 42;

    for (auto i : cost[3])
        std::cout << i << ' ';
}
```

Comment: I did as you said and filled the list with elements... i.e initialized it all to zeros. Now another error occurs it says "Exception thrown at 0x00F13CD9 in Algorithms.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x38B7ABD4." It showed this error opening the "list" library and pointing to the 852 line

Comment: I think I'll just switch to vector .. list it getting on my nerves